# How to properly click a button that is covered by a popunder?

Tags: c#, selenium, phantomjs

I am filling out a form on a webpage. The submit button is at the bottom of the form, however it is covered by a popunder. When I try to do `element.click()`, it simply throws an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException

and says:

> Element is not clickable at point (570,793). Other element would receive the click: `<html of popunder element>`

I can scroll down, somehow, to view it, but there must be some other methods. I've tried setting the browser window height to a massive number, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an Adjust extension method to any IWebElements to scroll it to center of the window, something like:

```
public static IWebElement Adjust(this IWebElement element)
{
    var windowHeight = Convert.ToInt32(((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return window.innerHeight;"));
    var scrollPage = element.Location.Y - windowHeight/2;

    ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, " + scrollPage + ")");
    return element;
}
```

To use you need to call **Adjust()** before Click method:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("your-selector")).Adjust().Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up scrolling down, but this only works when the button is known to be at a fixed coordinate, so this is not the best answer. However, it is an answer, so I'll post the code.

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, 700)");
```